# MySQL Inner join on closest row on a table sorted by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(it has multiple fields, but have omitted for simplicity. Also my schema is not fully normalized and I am not able to change that):
`AgentProducts`

`ProductId, AgentId, Fees`

Note that from time to time, this table will be updated so that a given `ProductId` will have a different `AgentId, Fees` at different instants of time. Each time that happens, an entry is made into the `AgentProductsHistory` table.

I want to track the assignment history of a product. For that I have
`AgentProductsHistory`:

`ApId,ProductId,AgentId,AssignmentDate`

Now my task is to generate a report of fees for a given product for a given `DATE_IN_QUESTION`.
For this, I need to do `inner join` on `AgentProducts` and `AgentProductHistory` on `AgentProducts.ProductId = AgentProductsHistory.ProductId AND <expression>`

I want to know what should be this `<expression>` which is supposed to first sort the `AgentProductsHistory` (grouped by `ProductId`) based on `AssignmentDate` and find out that row which has date that is just greater than the `DATE_IN_QUESTION`.

E.g. see this sample of `AgentProductsHistory`

```
ApId ProductId AgentId AssignmentDate
1    QWXR      1       01 JUL 2022   
2    QWXR      3       21 JUN 2022      
3    QWXR      2       07 JUN 2022 
4    QWXR      4       14 JUN 2022
```

Please ignore the date format above as it is just to explain.
In my case, I want to find out what was the fees for agent for selling a product on `20 JUN 2022`
Is this even possible? Or I will need to add a `DateTo` and `DateFrom` for `AgentProductsHistory` instead of `AssignmentDate` (Which I feel should be redundant IMO)?

Comment: ' Is this even possible' - You don't know what the fee was at any particular time.

Comment: @P.Salmon this is available in the AgentProducts table(AgentId,Fees). So if we find out which was the agent(AgentId) that was selling that product at a given instant of time, we can find this out.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case from the published table so only 1 fee exists per ProductId, AgentId,

Comment: @P.Salmon edited question to make it more clear. The AgentProducts table will be updated from time to time so that a new agent is linked with a ProductId. And in such cases, an entry will be made in the AgentProductsHistory table.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: *see this sample of AgentProductsHistory* This data looks like one produced by OracleDB, not by MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully..

Comment: @Akina I mentioned in my question that `Please ignore the date format above as it is just to explain`. Do I still need to change the sample?

Comment: *Do I still need to change the sample?* You'd read the provided link and provide sample source data (p.5) + desired output for id (p.3) with detailed explanations.